# Associating a models using foreign keys

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

My goal is to have a setup where Users create Grants as funders and then other users are matched with grants as reachers.  I've been playing around with a few options for the model set up such as:

```
class Grant < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :funder, class_name:"User", foreign_key:"funder_id"
 has_many :matches
 has_many :researchers, class_name: "User", source: :user, through: :matches


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :matches
has_many :grants, through: :matches


class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :grant


Or ——————————————————————



 class Grant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :funder_matches, :foreign_key => :researcher_id, :class_name => "Match"
  has_many :researcher_matches, :foreign_key => :funder_id, :class_name => "Match"
  has_many :researchers, through: :researcher_matches
  has_many :funders, through: :funder_matches



class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :grant
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :funder, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :researcher, :class_name => "User"

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :matches
  has_many :grants, through: :matches
```

and then in the meantime grants are created by admin by visiting the users profile and passing in the user_id.

In the grant model I have:

```
def create_grant_with_associations(current_user)
    current_user.grants << self
    self.funder = current_user
    self.save
 end
```

I also have funder_id on the Grants table and in the grant controller I have

```
def create
    @grant = @@user.grants.build(grant_params)
      if @grant.save
        @grant.create_grant_with_associations(@@user)
        flash[:info] = "The grant was successfully created" 
        redirect_to @grant
      else
        render 'new'
    end
  end
```

and then finally I have a collection select to allow admin to select grants and match them with the user.

```
<h4>Match a grant:</h4>
  <%= form_for @user, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal', :multipart => true }  do |f| %> 
      <div class="field "> 
        <%= f.label :grants, "Select Grant" %> 
        <%= f.collection_select(:grant_ids, Grant.all, :id, :name,{:include_blank => 'Show No Grants Matched'},  :multiple => true) %> 
      </div>   
  <%= f.submit "Create Match", class: "btn btn-primary"%>
  <% end %>
```

The problem I'm having now is that when i use the collection select it overrides the funder association. Am I on the right track?